# ManyToMany model error

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have a Cruise offer class related to a model called SpecialInterest.  I now realize that I have the same exact thing going on in my LandOffer model (elsewhere).  So I want to get rid of the cruise.SpecialInterest and replace it with the land.SpecialInterest.

This is my error:
Error: One or more models did not validate:
cruise.cruiseoffer: 'special_interest' has an m2m relation with model land.models.SpecialInterest, which has either not been installed or is abstract.

I dropped the CruiseOffer table, but when I syncdb I fail.

Help?

```
class CruiseOffer(models.Model):
  id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
  name = models.CharField(max_length=300) # Field name made lowercase.
  name_enca = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
  name_frca = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True) # Field name made lowercase.
  supplier = models.ForeignKey('CruiseSupplier')
  #special_interest = models.ManyToManyField('SpecialInterest')
  special_interest = models.ManyToManyField('land.models.SpecialInterest')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%6d %s" % (self.id, self.name,)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right syntax is:

```
from land.models import SpecialInterest
...
class Crui...
    ...
    special_interest = models.ManyToManyField(SpecialInterest)
```

Comment: Is `land` listed into settings installed applications?

Comment: After spinning for a day, I looked again at @danihp response and realized that I had quotes around my SpecialInterest table.  Removed them and I am now in business.